# How to extract timezone from timestamp in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql, timestamp, timezone

I have two column: ts and ts_pst, their default values are `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` and `timezone('pst'::text, now())` respectively.

```
SELECT ts, ts_pst
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  _id = xxx;
```

The result is like following. As you can see, they are different, like 8 hours apart:

```
"2021-01-01 19:15:44.779937+00" "2021-01-01 11:15:44.779937+00"
```

However, when I try to extract timezone from them, however the time zone are both zero.

```
SELECT Extract(timezone FROM ts), Extract(timezone FROM ts_pst) 
FROM   table_a 
WHERE  _id = xxx;
```

Both are zeros!

```
0   0
```

I was expecting the second timezone to be `-8`. Am I misunderstanding something?

------Additional edits------

The type the columns:

```
ts timestamp with time zone DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
ts_pst timestamp with time zone DEFAULT timezone('pst'::text, now()),
```

Comment: Your columns need to be of a type able to store the timezone information. What are the types you your two columns?

Comment: @MichalT they are both `timestamp with time`. Just updated the question description.

Comment: First the `ts_pst` field is pretty much useless. `timestamptz` stores timestamps as `UTC`, so just do the rotation to `PST` from the `ts` field in the `SELECT`. Second I'm betting your `timezone` is set to `UTC` in the database. In `psql` `Show timezone;` will tell you.  That would explain the `timezone = 0`. In `psql` do `set timezone= US/Pacific
` and then you will see something different(-25200).